# Ubuntu 14 Virtual host file not working with IP (e.g. 123.123.123.123/supervisor2)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2

I have a virtual host file **/etc/apache2/sites-available/supervisor2.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin myemail@test.com
ServerName ???
DocumentRoot /var/www/supervisor/public_html

<Directory /var/www/supervisor/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have added the website via: **a2ensite supervisor2**

I have confirmed that **/var/www/supervisor2** exists, and I want to access it via "**123.123.123.123/supervisor2**" but I get:

**Not Found** 
The requested URL /supervisor2 was not found on this server.

Any help would be appreciated to help me get this working.

**Update:**

I actually just had to edit my 000-default.conf file and add:

**Alias /supervisor2 /var/www/supervisor/public_html**

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of "supervisor2" in your configuration.  Don't forget to restart Apache after correction.

Comment: This is the part I'm not sure how to do. I have a .conf file that works with a www domain which points to a /var/www location e.g.:

    `ServerName mywebsite.ca  
     ServerAlias www.mywebsite.ca`    
  
But how would I do this if I want to type in the web address as `123.123.123.123/supervisor2`?